# Rails test service object with MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm trying to understand MiniTest in Rails 6 to use it instead of RSpec. Practically all the materials I found concern two things: controller and model tests and they don't touch such an important thing as service objects. I've got below service object which simply updates three User fields - status, status_updated_at and failed_attempts. To simplify the example, I will omit the remaining conditions.

```
  class FailedAttributes
    def initialize(user)
      @user = user
    end

    def call
      transaction do
        user.class.update_counters(user.id, failed_attempts: 1)
        user.update(status: 'inactive', status_updated_at: DateTime.now)
      end
    end
```

RSpec test would be very simple but how to write it using MiniTest? I've got simple:

```
require 'test_helper'

class FailedAttributesTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @user = users(:registered)
  end
end
```

And how to pass `@user` variable to run the class and check if `@user` was updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minitest is really just a very bare bones TDD setup with very few opinions on how to write your tests.

`Minitest::Test` does not have a built in equivilent to `let/let!` or the implicit subject in RSpec. Instead dependencies are quite often setup in the `setup` block:

```
require 'test_helper'

class FailedAttributesTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Arrange
  setup do
    @user = users(:registered)
    @service = FailedAttributes.new(@user)
  end

  def test_does_something
    # Act
    @service.call
    # Assert
    assert_equals(@user.reload.foo, 'bar')
  end
end
```

You can if you want create memoized helper methods somewhat like `let` in RSpec:

```
require 'test_helper'

class FailedAttributesTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def test_does_something
    # Act
    service.call
    # Assert
    assert_equal(user.reload.foo, 'bar')
  end

  private

  def user
    @user ||= users(:registered)
  end

  def service
    @service ||= FailedAttributes.new(user) 
  end
end
```

As to how to test service objects - thats really a close to impossible subject to cover as service objects are really just a design pattern which consists of writing simple objects that perform a single job and take all needed input either as constructor or method arguments. Testing them is actually not that unlike testing any other type of object.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand one thing. Is there any standard that defines when I should use the `test` block instead of `def some_method_name; end` ?

Comment: No, the `test` method really just defines methods under the hood and is generally preferred as its easier to read `test "some really long description"` then `test_some_really_long_description`.

Comment: Edited a bit - `MiniTest::Spec` does have `let` but `ActiveSupport::TestCase` inherits from `Minitest::Test`. `MiniTest::Spec` is a mini BDD framework of pretty shifty quality.

Comment: That's wired, I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'assert_equals' for #<FailedAttributesTest:0x00007fe80197a900>`

Comment: Above error exists only for `test 'sth' do` block. If I change it to `def 'sth'; end` the test will not start - `0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips`

Comment: Sorry it's `assert_equal`. This is one of the things I hate with TDD, plus the fact that it's impossible for me to remember the order of the args. `</rant>`